# A number $n$ is chosen at random such that $1 <=n <=220$ , What's the probability that $n^{16}$ will has that remainder of $1$ upon division by $5$?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

> An natural  number $n$ is chosen at random  such that $1 <=n <=220$ , What's the probability that $n^{16}$ will has  that remainder of $1$ upon division by $5$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Have you made any attempts?

Comment: Hint: Interpret $n$ as an element of $\mathbb Z_5$ so that $n^4=1$ by Fermat.

Comment: Another way to improve the quality of the question is to use [$\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020), which I see you did, but you could also use `$\le$` or $\le$ too. [See this for more ideas.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/)

Comment: @abiessu Seems that showing some effort is not necessary to get a full answer (not just a hint) :(

Comment: @mdave16 Why do users so often criticize the layout rather than the missing context or lack of effort ?

Comment: @Peter, i'm not sure why, but i do know that it works (also i didn't personally criticise the lack of effort since it had already been done by abiessu) I think the question has been asked in meta before though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisely for which $n$ is it true that $n^{16} \equiv 1 \mod 5$?

Well, note that it's clearly not true for $n$ a multiple of five. However, if it is not, then $n$ and $5$ are co prime, so by Fermat's theorem, $n^4 \equiv 1 \mod 5$. Therefore, $n^{16} = (n^4)^4 \equiv 1 \mod 5$. Hence, precisely those $n$ which are not multiples of $5$, satisfy the above equation.

There are $44$ multiples of $5$ between $1$ and $220$. Therefore, we see that the answer is $\frac{220-44}{220} = \frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: Thank you. Your question was probably downvoted, along with my answer, for lack of effort. But I answered this question because I liked the way it was phrased, and found it interesting. Please ensure you provide context to your question next time, so that you can avoid downvotes and have a better experience on this site.

Comment: A hint would be a good compromise. On the one hand, the asker gets help and can try to solve the problem alone (more help can be given, if the asker still is stuck). On the other hand, the asker would be encouraged to do some work alone. Giving a full answer does not give the asker the chance to do something alone.